# iPhone 6 Screen Resolution with CSS and JavaScript

Tags: html, css, center

I read that the iPhone 6 Screen Resolution is 750*1334. But when I have for example a text, etc. and center it, it is not centered precisely. But when I use 50% with CSS, then it is centered precisely. A simple ID with DIV:

`"margin-left: 375px;"`

`"margin-left: 50%;"`

Comment: I wrote the "margin-left: 750px;" wrong it should be "margin-left: 375px;" but it is not centered.

Answer (score 0):

Try using meta viewport in the head of your html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

this should fit the content according to the device

Comment: Also I see your new, just make sure to properly format your questions and make sure your code is formatted correctly in context to the rest

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this also doesn't centered it.

Answer (score 0):

Please look here for the code:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWSYYEYX7IV5

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just remove `margin-left: 375px;`
and add `text-align: center;` (in `#text`)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  #header {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
  }
  #text {
    text-align: center;

  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="text">Test</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend not using px or margin: attributes for centering too much as this can cause trouble later in development in a website

Comment: OK, but what is when I use something other than a text? Also I need to use margin-left because I have multiple objects which I do center.

Comment: text align is a specific attribute , margin-left only defines the space between the object and the left side, the bigger the margin the furthur away it is

Comment: Another problem is when I use media queries. When the iPhone 6 is not 750 px, how do I know the exactly resolution?

Comment: Maybe I describe my problem not exactly. screen.width*devicePixelRatio returns 750px for iPhone 6, but in fact it is not so. Therefore I can't center it with 375 px, and I can't use media queries because the iPhone 6 is not 750 px?

Comment: Please check off my answer if this helped